# How to sort set of coordinates in ascending order by distance from point ( x1,y1)?

Tags: c++, stl

I have `std::set<std::pair<float,float>>` which represents points on map ( 2d , x and y value) and I have one point with values x1 and y1. How to sort set in ascending order by distance from point ( x1,y1) ?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate distances?

Comment: Write your own predicate to check wether the point you are adding in set has lesser or greater distance from given point and use that compare method to create set, set will automatically sort its element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an ordered container, and ordering happens upon insertion, depending on a sorting criteria which can be specified with a second template argument. So use a `set` with a predicate which returns true or false based on the distance to the reference point.

```
struct DistanceCompare
{
  DistanceCompare(const std::pair<float,float>& point) : point_(point) {} 
  bool operator()(const std::pair<float,float>& lhs, 
                  const std::pair<float,float>& rhs) const
  {
    return distance2(lhs) < distance2(rhs);
  };

 private:
  float distance2(const std::pair<float,float>& point) const
  {
    // calculate distance squared between point and point_
    const float x = point.first  - point_.first;
    const float y = point.second - point_.second;
    return x*x + y*y;

  }
  std::pair<float, float> point_;
};

....
std::pair<float,float> refPoint = ....;
DistanceCompare comp(refPoint);
std::set<std::pair<float, float>, DistanceCompare> pointSet(comp);
```

It is enough to compare the distance squared, thus avoiding calls to `std::sqrt`.

Comment: You forgot to pass an instance of `DistanceCompare` to the pointSet's constructor. As shown, your example won't compile because `DistanceCompare` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for answer. I added code like you said but when I try to insert in pointSet I got error  error C2228: left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union . Any idea ?

Comment: @Damir OK, there were a couple of errors that I fixed, see edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

The distance between two points can be calculated as follows:

```
xd = x2-x1;
yd = y2-y1;
Distance = SquareRoot(xd*xd + yd*yd);
```

And the value of `Distance` can be used as sorting parameter.